# 'tsConfig' is not found in schema - Migrating tslint to eslint (Angular v11)

Tags: angular, eslint, tslint, tsconfig

```
npx ng lint <projectName>

> nx run <projectName>:lint 
'tsConfig' is not found in schema
```

I used to do the Migration from tslint to eslint. I followed this article:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/tslint-eslint-migration

I don't know why I get this error.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same sssue, and fixed it by change some lines in angular.json.
I fixed it at options:

```
"architect": {
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": [
          "libs/domain/tsconfig.lib.json",
          "libs/domain/tsconfig.spec.json"
        ],
        "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "!libs/backoffice-cockpit/domain/**/*"] 
      }
    }
}
```

i deleted the lines "tsConfig" & "exclude"
and added:

```
"lintFilePatterns": [
          "libs/domain/src/**/*.ts",
          "libs/domain/src/**/*.html"
        ]
```